# How to use SQL Server 2005 Express integrated in VS2008?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, sql-server-express

I have installed Visual Studio 2008 on my laptop running Windows Vista Ultimate 32 bit.

I am unable to create database using `Server Explorer -> Data Connections -> Add new SQL Server database`. The `Create New SQL Server database` window is displayed but there is no name in the Server name dropdown. I don't know why its happening. Initially I was not sure whether SQL Server Express is installed or not.

But now I installed the Express edition separately. Same problem is there. What should I do?

Comment: Make your question some clear by using code parts if it is there.

Answer (score 0):

The SQL Server service must be running. Also, as I recall the box you speak of makes no attempt to enumerate instances; you must type them in manually (then they are saved in an MRU type of list for future connections).

If it's on the same system as you are developing from, you can possibly just type `localhost` in the box and it should connect.

Comment: I did, Its ok... But when I execute "CREATE DATABASE ABC" command through Management Studio, i got an error message stating "CREATE DATABASE Permission denied in database Master." What is the reason ?